# Perl replacing \ in a string

Tags: perl

I want to replace second occurrences of back slash in string, It could be very easy.

string

```
$ra = '\\Test\C$\temp';
```

output should be like this

```
"\\Test/C$/temp"
```

search and replace changes everything in the string

```
$ra =~ s/\\/\//g; makes output to "/Test/C$/temp"
```

any insight highly appreciated

Comment: Will the first backslash be preceded by a backslash always?

Comment: By "second occurrences," do you mean "occurrences other than the first"?  What if the first character of the string isn't a backslash?

Comment: Apologize for some confusion. The final output I would like to have is "\\Test/C$/temp"

First two occurrences of backslash remains there rest remains to modified.

Comment: I always get the input similar to this though the string length could be different but the format is same

Comment: So you really want `$ra = '\\\\Test\C$\temp'`, right?  The first backslash is escaped to a single backslash in the input as it stands.

Comment: Yes that is correct it should look like that, while processing the string. But as I said input looks like \\Test\C$\temp. I have to add \\ later to process it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but you can use the e option:

```
$ra =~ s!^(.*?\\)(.*)!my ($e,$f)=($2,$1);$e=~s/\\/\//g;$f.$e!e;
```

or using split:

```
my @v = split /\\+/, $ra;
$ra = (shift @v) . '\\' . join("/", @v);
```

Answer (score 2):

"I want to replace ... back slash in string [with slashes]"

```
s,\\,/,g;
```

"First two occurrences of backslash remains"

```
s,(?<!^)(?<!^\\)\\,/,g;
```

Two zero-width negative lookbehind assertions are required as lookbehinds can't be of variable width.  They succeed if the backlash isn't preceded by the start of a line or by the start of a line and then a backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I couldn't get the expected result

Answer (score 1):

The string literal

```
 '\\Test\C$\temp';
```

creates the string

```
 \Test\C$\temp
```

So first, you need to use

```
 $ra = '\\\\Test\\C$\\temp';
```

Or if you want to cut corners,

```
 $ra = '\\\Test\C$\temp';
```

Then you can simply do

```
 $ra =~ s{(?<!^)(?<!^\\)\\}{/}g;
```

Note that Windows considers

```
 //Test/C$/temp
```

to be completely equivalent to

```
 \\Test\C$\temp
```

so I don't know why you're trying to accomplish what you said you wanted to accomplish.